# performing a search on a form - search in the filtered list of entries displayed in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i really need some help on this. I searched the internet but couldn't find a single solution to my problem.

I have got an index.html.erb file which displays some records which have been retrieved using a rather complex find_by_sql. Please see code below:

```
def index
@refprobes = Refprobe.paginate_by_sql ["select * from ref_probe
                                      where RPR_OID in
                                (SELECT DISTINCT RPR_OID
                                FROM REF_PROBE
                                JOIN ISH_PROBE ON RPR_OID = PRB_MAPROBE
                                JOIN ISH_SUBMISSION ON PRB_SUBMISSION_FK = SUB_OID
                                JOIN SEC_USER_PI ON USP_PI_ID = SUB_PI_FK
                                WHERE USP_USER_FK = " + session[:user_id]+ ")"], :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

Now i want to include a search field on top of my index.html.erb, which will allow user to filter those displayed entries based on the value inputted in the search field.

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

The above code does not fit my requirements as i don't want to search through all the records in the table. I want to restrict my search to only those entries displayed my index.html.erb.

How can i do this?

Many many thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about [scopes](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/)